# Discord4J API (Java)| How do I get the owner of the server's username and store it in a string?

Tags: java, discord, discord4j

I am making a bot for discord and I want to get the username of the owner of the server and put it into a string.

Code of my ProcessCommand Class where I want it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void proccessCommand(IMessage message, String prefix) {

    IUser sender = message.getAuthor();
    IChannel channel = message.getChannel();
    IGuild guild = message.getGuild();

    String[] command = message.getContent().toLowerCase().replaceFirst(prefix, "").split(" ");

    if(command[0].equals("rules")) {
        channel.sendMessage("ImConor's Discord Server Rules!" + "\r\n" + "No Racism, No Alts, No Disrespect to ANYONE, No Ban Evasion" );
    }
    else if(command[0].equals("restart")) {
        message.delete();
        channel.sendMessage("@everyone, I am restarting! Please do NOT use any ModBot commands!");
    }else if(command[0].equals("ping")) {
        channel.sendMessage("Pong!");
    }else if(command[0].equals("start")) {
        if (message.getAuthor() == *string of username here*) {
            message.delete();
            channel.sendMessage("@everyone, I have returned!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this documentation [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/austinv11/Discord4j/2.8.4/javadoc/).
You already have a `IGuild` variable named `guild` from your `message.getGuild()` method.

And if you search into the documentation for **owner** (Ctrl + F helps), you will see a `getOwner()` method for `IGuild` class, which results a `IUser` and that object basically contains the details about the server's owner.

Finally, `IUser` object have a `getName()` method.

So in short, you can do `String ownerName = guild.getOwner().getName();`
Or simply a `IUser ownerObject = guild.getOwner()` and do whatever you want with the user object of the owner next.